# Nepomuk is not indexing files

Tags: kubuntu, kde, nepomuk

I'm noticing the following problems:

- When I click on **Desktop Search -> Basic Settings -> Details**, I get "File indexing service is not running" and the *Indexed files* field reals "Calculating..." but never actually produces a number.
- When using krunner, home run, etc, if I type a filename on my computer, it does not show up.

(EDIT) When I try to index something on the command line, this happens:

```
$ touch foobar
$ nepomukindexer foobar 
nepomukindexer(9660)/nepomuk (strigi service): SimpleIndexError:  "No such object path '/datamanagement'"                            
nepomukindexer(9660)/nepomuk (strigi service): "No such object path '/datamanagement'"                                               
No such object path '/datamanagement'
```

Nepomuk, Semantic Desktop, File Indexer, and Email Indexer are all enabled under Basic Settings. This is under Kubuntu 13.04, though it was also an issue under 12.10 with the KDE 4.10 PPA.

It appears that Nepomuk simply isn't indexing files and isn't generally working, but I'm not sure where to look for log files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could happen if you upgraded from 12.10 and kept the /home folder.
To fix it, I had to purge the Nepomuk database and re-index everything.

In my case, I did:

```
 qdbus org.kde.NepomukServer /nepomukserver quit
 rm -rf $(kde4-config --localprefix)/share/apps/nepomuk/repository/
```

Then, I re-indexed the PDF files:

```
 cd; find . -name "*.pdf" | xargs -n1 -I{} nepomukindexer {}
```

...and ODT files:

```
 cd; find . -name "*.odt" | xargs -n1 -I{} nepomukindexer {}
```